# zend framework 3 and doctrine authentication

Tags: symfony, zend-framework, doctrine-orm, doctrine, zf3

Started working on **zf3** project with **Doctrine** but ran into this problem.

This is my Factory

```
public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, Array $options = null) {
    $authenticationService = $container->get('doctrine.authenticationservice.orm_default');
    $entityManager = $container->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default');
    return new $requestedName($entityManager, $authenticationService);
}
```

and in controller

```
public function __construct(EntityManager $em, $auth)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $em;
        $this->authService = $auth;
    }


public function loginAction()
{
    //...
}
```

in config

```
'authentication' => [
         'orm_default' => [
             'object_manager' => 'Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager',
             'identity_class' => 'Application\Entity\Users',
             'identity_property' => 'username',
             'credential_property' => 'password'
         ],
     ],
...
```

but it gives the error

this line

```
 $authenticationService = $container->get('doctrine.authenticationservice.orm_default');
```

gives me the error

> Class 'Zend\Session\Container' not found

Comment: Do you have `zend-session` module installed?

Comment: yes required it and now working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have the [`zend-session` module](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-session) installed?
For doctrine authentication to work you need to install this dependency.

It seems the class `Zend\Session\Container` is unavailable which suggests that this module is not properly installed.